# Using R how do I change the data in a Column from a Letter to a Word

Tags: r

I have a column in my spreadsheet called CourseType and the value in the column is either O, OS or C. I want to change the letters to read Online, Onsite.

How would I do this using R?

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Welcome at SO! Please note that questions shall contain a minimal reproducible example in R that construct example data. Also indicate the expected result for the example data. This makes it easier for us to answer (without wasting time and to be sure to provide what you need). THX :-)

Comment: Do you also (implicitly) ask how to read an Excel file or "just" how to recode column values?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the dataframe is called df and the column is named CourseType, you can use an `ifelse` statement if the options to be replaced are limited. This is similar to the nested IF-ELSE in excel:

```
df$CourseType_new <- ifelse(df$CourseType == "O", "Online", 
                     ifelse(df$CourseType == "OS", "OnSite", "something else"))
```

If you have more values, I'd suggest using a lookup table

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `ifelse` cascades (e. g. in case of many different codes) you can use this approach:

```
# Construct example data
df <- data.frame(CourseType = c("C", "O", "O", "OS", "OS", "C"), teacher = c("Joe", "Jane"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#   CourseType teacher
# 1          C     Joe
# 2          O    Jane
# 3          O     Joe
# 4         OS    Jane
# 5         OS     Joe
# 6          C    Jane

# Do recode by filtering the lines
df$CourseType[df$CourseType == "O"]  <- "Online"
df$CourseType[df$CourseType == "OS"] <- "OnSite"

df
#    CourseType teacher
# 1          C     Joe
# 2     Online    Jane
# 3     Online     Joe
# 4     OnSite    Jane
# 5     OnSite     Joe
# 6          C    Jane

# Note: The non-matching CourseTypes are left unchanged!
```

One drawback is that you have no `else` part where you can set the non-recodes values to a default value... So a better approach would be to "enrich" your `data.frame` by adding the recoded value to a new column:

```
df$CourseTypeRecoded[df$CourseType == "O"]  <- "Online"
df$CourseTypeRecoded[df$CourseType == "OS"] <- "OnSite"

df
#   CourseType teacher CourseTypeRecoded
# 1          C     Joe              <NA>
# 2          O    Jane            Online
# 3          O     Joe            Online
# 4         OS    Jane            OnSite
# 5         OS     Joe            OnSite
# 6          C    Jane              <NA>
```

You could then set the `NA` values (which indicate an recode failure) to a default value, e. g.

```
df$CourseTypeRecoded[is.na(df$CourseTypeRecoded)] <- "(invalid code)"
```